# Application Load Balancer Health Check unhealthy instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, aws-application-load-balancer, health-check

Here is my situation. I have an EC2 instance running in a private subnet. On the instance I have two partitions. The application I have running is on the larger partition of the instance. My application load balancer has the instance pushing traffic on ports `80` & `443`.

However, in the application load balancer I am getting an unhealthy instance. I've verified the application is accurate but am still getting this unhealthy instance. The error code I am getting is 502 (bad gateway). My question is maybe I have configure my application load balancer to do health checks not on the root drive but on the partition where the application is sitting? If that is the possible route, how do I implement it?

Comment: Can you post screenshot or setup of your Load balancer, target groups, listeners and security groups?

Comment: If you are talking about disk partitions it is irrelevant here. 1. login to the instance via SSH or RDP and confirm that the application is running on both ports 2. check the instance security group allowing traffic from load balancer.

Comment: I checked the ports the application is running on. I see 80 and not 443. The way I have the load balancer set up is to do redirects on port 80 to 443. I’m assuming this is happening because application is open on 80 in the Linux instance and not 443. Once the load balancer sees something come in that is on 80, it is supposed to redirect and go to 443 but then spits out a bad gateway because there is nothing running on 443? I hope I am making sense of this. If that is the case, how do I have the Linux instance open 443 and have the application run on that too?